# What does cv::normalize(_src, dst, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);

Tags: opencv

What does the `cv::normalize(_src, dst, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);` do in OpenCV?

I went through  the documentation and was unable to understand what `alpha`, `beta`, `NORM_MINMAX` and `CV_8UC1` actually do. I am aware alpha sets the lower and beta the higher bound. `CV_8UC1` stands for an 8-bit unsigned single channel. But what exactly these arguments do to the picture is what I am unable to comprehend.

Comment: **Use `CV_8U` instead for the `dtype` argument.** “[_`dtype`: when negative, the output array has the same type as `src`; otherwise, **it has the same number of channels as `src`** and the depth = `CV_MAT_DEPTH(dtype)`._](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd)” The `dst` will always have the same number of channels as the `src`.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

When the `normType` is `NORM_MINMAX`, `cv::normalize` normalizes `_src` in such a way that the min value of `dst` is `alpha` and max value of `dst` is `beta`. `cv::normalize` does its magic using only scales and shifts (i.e. adding constants and multiplying by constants).

`CV_8UC1` says how many channels `dst` has.

The documentation here is pretty clear: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#normalize

Comment: What do alpha and beta mean in the image. As far as I know alpha stood for minimum range and beta for max.So if I am converting to grayscale shouldnt alpha be 0 and beta be 1 if I am using a single channel?

Comment: alpha and beta are the highest and lowest value in the dst image, respectively.

Comment: So when I am using a single channel it should ideally be 0 to 1 right? Or am I mistaken here?

Comment: 0 to 255 are the physical limits of your array: you can't store anything above 255 or below 0. What values to use it depends on what limits you need: if you use 5 and 20 there won't be anything below 5 or above 20.

Comment: But single channels simply use 0 and 1 right? So the 0 and 255 are kind of redundant?

Comment: No... single channel use one channel but the signal is between 0 and 255.

Comment: OKay. I guess now I need to read up more on channels and what they are. Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you use this function to normalize a set of images best on mean and std of all images not just a single image?

Comment: @carlosdc `alpha and beta are the highest and lowest value in the dst image, respectively.` isn't it the reverse; alpha is lower limit so it is the minimum and beta is upper limit so it is the maximum in the dst?

Comment: 0 to 255 limits are related to `CV_8UC1`, it is different for other types

Comment: “_`dtype`: when negative, the output array has the same type as `src`; otherwise, **it has the same number of channels as `src`** and the depth = `CV_MAT_DEPTH(dtype)`._” No, you shouldn’t specify how many channels `dst` has, because it is always the same with the `src`. **Use `CV_8U` instead.**

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of normalization in Opencv.

Try running samples in the [Online OpenCV-Flow](https://opencvflow.org/) tool to better understand each type.

[image: Normalize Sample]