# Making an array of Mat type objects. The output window shows the same frame

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, graphics, opencv3.0

Following is my code. It has an array of Mat type objects. And I add the Mat made inside the for loop as imgArr[index] = img. But when I output all the frames to see the animation on the window, it just shows the last frame and shows the same frame.

```
namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.

int numFrames = endFrame - startFrame;          // Total number of frames
Mat imgArr[100];

for(long int FrameNumber = startFrame; FrameNumber < endFrame; FrameNumber++){

    fp.seekg( BytesPerFrame*(FrameNumber), std::ios::beg);
    char buffer[BytesPerImage];

    fp.read(buffer, BytesPerImage);
    short image[512*512];

    short min = 20000, max=1000;


    for ( int i = 0; i < BytesPerImage; i=i+2 )
    {
        int a;
        a = floor(i/2)+1;
        //  take first character
        image[a] = (static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(buffer[i+1]))*256+static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(buffer[i])));
        if(image[a] < min){
            min = image[a];
        }
        if(image[a] > max){
            max = image[a];
        }

    }

    // Processing the image
    Mat img(512, 512, CV_16S, image);
    img -= (min);
    img *= (32767/max); // (330000/2500);
    img *= ((max/min)/2) + 2;    // 16;
    imgArr[FrameNumber-startFrame] = img;
}

for(int i = 0; i<numFrames; i++){
    imshow( "Display window", imgArr[i]);                   // Show our image inside it.
    waitKey(50);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried 'Mat::copyTo()' instead?

Comment: your problem is that you dont copy the images but only link mat to the (fixed) memory address of "image" which will be the same for each mat. try  imgArr[FrameNumber-startFrame] = img.clone(); instead to deep copy the image memory for each mat. or use a flag to copy menory wgen creating img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things you are not getting right with your code. I will try to list them:

```
namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.

int numFrames = endFrame - startFrame;          // Total number of frames
Mat imgArr[100];
```

First problem: What if your number of frames `numFrames` is bigger than `100`? This would be safer:

```
std::vector<Mat> imgVector;
imgVector.reserve(numFrames);
```

And then at each new frame you `push_back` an image. Let's continue.

```
for(long int FrameNumber = startFrame; FrameNumber < endFrame; FrameNumber++){

    fp.seekg( BytesPerFrame*(FrameNumber), std::ios::beg); //Hmmm, when did you compute BytesPerFrame?
    char buffer[BytesPerImage]; //This is actually not C++, you probably even got a warning
```

You should replace `char buffer[BytesPerImage]` with `char* buffer = new char[BytesPerImage];`. You should also preallocate this intermediate buffer *before* the loop, so that you have to allocate it only once and use it many times. Then, after the loop, you deallocate it: `delete[] buffer;`.

```
    fp.read(buffer, BytesPerImage); //This seems fine
    short image[512*512]; //What's this?
```

What is `512`? I can understand looking at your code later, but you should define somewhere something like:

```
const int MYWIDTH = 512;
const int MYHEIGHT = 512;
const int BYTES_PER_IMAGE = MYWIDTH * MYHEIGHT * 2; //Maybe also the 2 should be a constant named `BYTES_PER_PIXEL`
```

Also, in this case let's allocate dynamically your data with `short* image = new short[MYWIDTH*MYHEIGHT];`. However, this is not going to work properly: unfortunately if you construct a `Mat` from an external buffer then deallocation won't be managed automatically. It's better to proceed the other way around: create your `Mat` and then use it as your buffer. It will look like this:

```
    Mat img(MYHEIGHT, MYWIDTH, CV_16S); //
    short* image = static_cast<short*> img.ptr();
```

One problem for further operations is that there might be "padding bytes". It's unlikely for a 512x512 image, but who knows. Please assert that the following will be true (See [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.9/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-step1)):

```
    (img.cols == img.step1() )
```

Then:

```
    short min = 20000, max=1000;
```

Why not `max=0`? Also, `min` could be initialized to 32767, or, more elegantly, to `std::numeric_limits<short>::max()` (`#include <limits.h>`)

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < BytesPerImage; i=i+2 )
    {
        int a;
        a = floor(i/2)+1;
        //  take first character
        image[a] = (static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(buffer[i+1]))*256+static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(buffer[i])));
        if(image[a] < min){
            min = image[a];
        }
        if(image[a] > max){
            max = image[a];
        }

    }
```

What I understand is: your input buffer is a 16bit image represented in big endian (the most significant byte comes before the least significant). The problems I see:

- what if the most significant byte is more than 127? Then your output value will overflow, as `128*256=32768 > 32767`.
- `floor(i/2)`. `floor` is not necessary: when you divide an integer value, it always return you the integer part of the result. Also, given the definition of your `for` loop, `i` is always even (you increment by 2) so the `floor` operation is *two times unnecessary*.
- `int a; a = floor(i/2)+1;` Remove the `+1`: think to the `0` indexed pixel and you'll immediately see you are assigning the value to the wrong pixel. With the last pixel you will actually have a segmentation fault. Your instruction becomes: `const int a = i/2;` (Ehi, how simple! :) )
- `image[a] = [...];`: Some of the cast you are doing are effectively necessary, especially the cast to `unsigned char`. I wonder, though, why don't you read `buffer` as buffer of `unsigned char` in the first place. All the `unsigned int` conversion could be omitted, as you don't need it for the least significant byte, while using the integer value `256` will already promote the pixel data
- A cameo: the `min` and `max` update function could be written as:

  ```
  min = std::min(min,image[a]);
  max = std::max(max,image[a]);
  ```

Let's proceed:

```
    // Processing the image
    Mat img(512, 512, CV_16S, image); //Already done, now remove
```

The Mat creation has already been taken care of.

```
   img -= (min);
   img *= (32767/max); // (330000/2500);
```

Ok, this has an easier equivalent using opencv library, we'll speak about it later. One problem here: this time you should really use a `float` for your division

```
   img *= (float(32767)/max);
```

By the way, I think in this case you wanted `max-min` at the denominator:

```
   img *= (float(32767)/(max-min));
```

The following I don't understand:

```
   img *= ((max/min)/2) + 2;    // 16;
```

Looking further,

```
 imgArr[FrameNumber-startFrame] = img;
```

given the change I suggested above (`std::vector` of images), this becomes:

```
 imgVector.push_back(img);
```

Finished!

---

One final note: it looks to me that what you are trying to do can be obtained with [`cv::normalize`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12023958/2436175). You could do:

```
cv::normalize(img, img, 0, 32767, NORM_MINMAX, CV_16UC1);
```

Comment: Note: [This guide](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252114/how-to-format-code-after-item-list) was relevant to get the formatting of this answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

if you construct a cv::Mat like this:

```
short pixels[512*512];
Mat img(512, 512, CV_16S, pixels);
```

the pointer to the pixels will be invalid, once you leave the scope.

either clone your Mat :

```
imgArr[FrameNumber-startFrame] = img.clone();
```

or pre-allocate it, and read into existing pixels:

```
Mat img(512, 512, CV_16S);
fp.read(img.data, BytesPerImage);
```

also: please replace the whole `for ( int i = 0; i < BytesPerImage; i=i+2 )` (horror!!) loop with:

```
double minVal,maxVal;
minMaxLoc(img, &minVal, &maxVal, 0,0);
```