# OpenCV matchTemplate minVal maxVal only return 0 and 1

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am running the example code for opencv's matchTemplate function.  I would like to know how "good" the match is and eliminate the data if the match quality is below a threshold.

```
    /// Do the Matching and Normalize
  matchTemplate( img, templ, result, match_method );
  normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  /// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
  double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
  Point matchLoc;

  minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );

  cout << "minVal" << minVal << "maxVal" << maxVal << endl;
```

I am printing out `minVal` and `maxVal` for matches running with different `templ` and `img` they all come out to 0 and 1.  How do I fix this so that they give me different values for match quality?

full example code I ran from opencv.org

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/// Global Variables
Mat img; Mat templ; Mat result;
char* image_window = "Source Image";
char* result_window = "Result window";

int match_method;
int max_Trackbar = 5;

/// Function Headers
void MatchingMethod( int, void* );

/** @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  /// Load image and template
  img = imread( argv[1], 1 );
  templ = imread( argv[2], 1 );

  /// Create windows
  namedWindow( image_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  namedWindow( result_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

  /// Create Trackbar
  char* trackbar_label = "Method: \n 0: SQDIFF \n 1: SQDIFF NORMED \n 2: TM CCORR \n 3: TM CCORR NORMED \n 4: TM COEFF \n 5: TM COEFF NORMED";
  createTrackbar( trackbar_label, image_window, &match_method, max_Trackbar, MatchingMethod );

  MatchingMethod( 0, 0 );

  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}

/**
 * @function MatchingMethod
 * @brief Trackbar callback
 */
void MatchingMethod( int, void* )
{
  /// Source image to display
  Mat img_display;
  img.copyTo( img_display );

  /// Create the result matrix
  int result_cols =  img.cols - templ.cols + 1;
  int result_rows = img.rows - templ.rows + 1;

  result.create( result_rows, result_cols, CV_32FC1 );

  /// Do the Matching and Normalize
  matchTemplate( img, templ, result, match_method );
  normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  /// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
  double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
  Point matchLoc;

  minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ONLY GETTING 0 AND 1 HERE ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  /// For SQDIFF and SQDIFF_NORMED, the best matches are lower values. For all the other methods, the higher the better
  if( match_method  == CV_TM_SQDIFF || match_method == CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
    { matchLoc = minLoc; }
  else
    { matchLoc = maxLoc; }

  /// Show me what you got
  rectangle( img_display, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );
  rectangle( result, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );

  imshow( image_window, img_display );
  imshow( result_window, result );

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple idea: remove the `normalize` call. It compresses the template match result into 0..1. See if `maxVal` gives you something meaningful if you don't normalize.

### Detailed explanation

What you see is entirely expected.

After `normalize(result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, ...)` the `result` matrix will have all values scaled (linearly) and shifted to fit the range `0..1`.
See: [normalize doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#normalize)
And:
[What does cv::normalize(_src, dst, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023958/what-does-cvnormalize-src-dst-0-255-norm-minmax-cv-8uc1)

`minMaxLoc` returns the values and locations of the min/max extrema.
Therefore after that `normalize`, you'll always get `minVal == 0`, `maxVal == 1`. See: [minMaxLoc doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#minmaxloc)

The interesting part of the `minMaxLoc` output here are the *locations* in `minLoc` and `maxLoc`. They will be the `Point` where the min and max are found.

If `matchTemplate` works well, you will see lots of low values and just one or a few peaks where the template matches well. `maxLoc` will have the coordinates of the top peak. The remaining values set by `minMaxLoc` tell you essentially nothing and you can ignore them. (As you can see in the sample code, some match methods will yield results that should interpreted the other way: low is good match, high is bad match -- in that case you should look at `minLoc`).

Comment: So are you saying that I should look at the result array before the normalize call?  I need to know how good a match is compared to another match with a different template image.  I was hoping that the maxVal would return a number like 0.569 and then when I run it with a different template it would return 0.754 so I know that the second run found a more likely match.

Comment: I removed the normal and it seems to be working well but I'm getting some negative values back for maxVal this is normal behavior right?

Comment: Depends on the `match_method`.