# Template Matching not working in different images

Tags: android, opencv, template-matching, matchtemplate

I am trying to compare different photos of faces to develop some kind of Face Recognition in Android. I am using OpenCV3 and match-Template , the problem is that if I cut a face in an image and use the same full image I get a match and all it's ok, but if the face is the same person's face but not from the same image I don't have a match and minVal and maxVal are both 0.
The code I'm using is from the sample code.
I have seen a lot of questions and answers
[OpenCV matchTemplate minVal maxVal only return 0 and 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42823214/opencv-matchtemplate-minval-maxval-only-return-0-and-1) for example, but I don't see a solution to my situation. 
Thank you very much, if you think I need to put my code here I'll Edit the question.

Comment: You should add the images you are working with to understand why the algorithm isn't working

Comment: Hi @RickM. the problem isn't happening with 2 images in concret, for example, if I have 2 Messi's photos (really similar, same position, only the face ) it returns 0 as "minVal" and "MaxVal" so I don't get a match although both faces are almost identical.
Otherwise if the face I am looking for is exactly the same then it returns a perfect match.